# Getting the indexPath "inside" a custom cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

My tableview consists of custom cells, and inside each cell/class I need to get the indexPath of that cell. I hope you understand what I mean. It's like if you would use a cellForRowAtIndexPath-function, but inside the custom cell class.

I assume there's some way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you need the index path for? What is the scenario?

Comment: I'm using a NSTimer inside the cell, and when that timer has reached 0 I want to set a value inside my core-data to true. @diederikh

Comment: Since you have already subclass the UITableViewCell, I would just add a property for indexPath and pass int the value whenever you create the cell.

Comment: @user523234 You mean just passing the indexPath.row and store it in the cell when it's created? If that's what you mean it's not favorable, because the tableView is dynamic.

Comment: Timers are tricky bastards ;-). You can keep a weak reference to the managed object in the cell and clear it in prepareForReuse. But it is better if you can handle it in the data source.

Comment: @diederikh A weak reference? Is that like a temporary reference? But really, is it such a difficult thing/bad idea to get the indexPath of the custom cell, it seems like such an easy solution.

Comment: The problem is that data changes (deletes, reordering, etc.) and the cell is always the last to know (if it does not get reused before that). So if your timer fires the object for index 4 might have changed and you update the wrong object. The controller/datasource keeps track of changes and is therefor the best place to handle this.

Comment: @diederikh Okay, so the cell will have trouble knowing its own indexpath, because it's the last one to know?

Comment: Yes. The data the cell represents may not be there anymore or at a different index path. Cell are being reused but you have no control over when or what the data situation is at that time. This is especially tricky if you use timers in cells.

Comment: @diedrikh But how can I then keep track of the indexpath in the data source? Or is that the point of a weak variable, that it changes when the indexpath changes?